# C# Regular Expression: Remove leading and trailing double quotes (")

Tags: c#, regex

If I have a string like below... what is the regular expression to remove the (optional) leading and trailing double quotes?   For extra credit, can it also remove any optional white space outside of the quotes:

```
string input = "\"quoted string\""   -> quoted string
string inputWithWhiteSpace = "  \"quoted string\"    "  => quoted string
```

(for C# using Regex.Replace)

Answer (score 43):

It's overkill to use `Regex.Replace` for this. Use [`Trim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4tt83f9.aspx) instead.

```
string output = input.Trim(' ', '\t', '\n', '\v', '\f', '\r', '"');
```

And if you only want to remove whitespace that's *outside* the quotes, retaining any that's inside:

```
string output = input.Trim().Trim('"');
```

Comment: I know it's not too common, but if your inner string starts or ends with any of those, you will trim them as well. For example, `Size 8"` or `"Size 8"""` (if it escapes the double quotes) will end up `Size 8`.

Answer (score 10):

Besides using a regular expression you can just use [`String.Trim()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zke31k1x.aspx) - much easier to read, understand, and maintain.

```
var result = input.Trim('"', ' ', '\t');
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace `^\s*"?|"?\s*$` with an empty string.

In C#, the regex would be:

```
string input = "  \"quoted string\"    "l
string pattern = @"^\s*""?|""?\s*$";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
string result = rgx.Replace(input, "");
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: `@"^\s*\"?|\"?\s*$"` is not possible in C#. In verbatim strings use `""` instead of `\"` for quotes. Also you don't need to create a new instance of Regex, just use Regex.Replace.

Answer (score 1):

I would use String.Trim method instead, but if you want regex, use this one:

```
@"^(\s|")+|(\s|")+$"
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a slightly modified version of another pattern that works pretty well for me.  I hope this helps for separating normal command-line parameters and double-quoted sets of words that act as a single parameter.

```
String pattern = "(\"[^\"]*\"|[^\"\\s]+)(\\s+|$)";
```

Comment: My own use:

// Eat first argument (as it's C# filename)
argsLine = new Regex("(\"[^\"]*\"|[^\"\\s]+)").Replace(argsLine, "");

Using similar regex approach. :-)

Answer (score 0):

My 2c, as I couldn't find what I was looking for. This verion removes the first pair of quotes and spaces on each side of them.

```cs
        public static string RemoveQuotes(string text)
        {
            var regex = new Regex(@"^\s*\""\s*(.*?)\s*\""\s*$");
            var match = regex.Match(text);
            if (match.Success && match.Groups.Count == 2)
            {
                return match.Groups[1].Value;
            }
            return text;
        }
```