# How to delete words contained in List<string> deleteCodeList from textile

Tags: c#, string, list, text-files, csv

I am wondering how can i delete words from my text file which are already contained in my `List<string> deleteCodeList = new List<string>();`. here i already have a large numbers of words in my deleteCodeList, and i want to search for this each words, **if words contained then `i want to delete that line`**.
My text file is `tab delimited`.

Codes:-

```
      while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var line = reader.ReadLine();
                var value = line.Split('\t');
               // here i am able to do words without double quotes
                bool deleteLine = value.Any(v => deleteCodeList.Any(w => v.Equals(w)));
                if (!deleteLine)
                {
                    sb.Append(line + Environment.NewLine);
                }
                //here i am able to do words with double quotes
                var values = line.Split('\t').Select(v => v.Trim(' ', '"'));
                bool deleteLines = values.Any(v => deleteCodeList.Any(w => v.Equals(w)));
                if (!deleteLines)
                {
                    sb.Append(line + Environment.NewLine);
                }
            }
```

My input text file

```
    Designator  MAX PN  Footprint   Center-X(mm)    Center-Y(mm)    Layer

      ggA1  100-0009    1206 - CAPACITOR    42.164  114.109 top
      C1A1  150-0009    1206 - CAPACITOR    42.164  114.109 bottom
      C21   100-0009    1206 - CAPACITOR    42.164  114.109 top
      CSA1  104-0009    1206 - CAPACITOR    42.164  114.109 bottom
      CSA1  107-0009    1206 - CAPACITOR    42.164  114.109 bottom
      MAA1  109-0009    1206 - CAPACITOR    42.164  114.109 bottom
```

Extension to the code:

```
     Designator MAX PN  Footprint   Center-X(mm)    Center-Y(mm)    Layer

       "C10"    "100-0009"  "1206 - CAPACITOR"  "122.492"   "69.469"    "bottom"
       "C100"   "100-0009"  "1206 - CAPACITOR"  "264.211"   "12.814"    "top"
       "C102"   "100-0009"  "1206 - CAPACITOR"  "251.346"   "11.201"    "bottom"
       "C105"   "100-0009"  "1206 - CAPACITOR"  "302.133"   "29.527"    "bottom"
       "C105A"  "100-0009"  "1206 - CAPACITOR"  "306.197"   "29.909"    "bottom"
       "C107"   "100-0009"  "1206 - CAPACITOR"  "273.685"   "29.527"    "bottom"
       "C107A"  "100-0009"  "1206 - CAPACITOR"  "277.749"   "29.401"    "bottom"
       "C113_C1"    "100-0009"  "1206 - CAPACITOR"  "165.214"   "101.854"   "bottom"
       "C113_C2"    "100-0009"  "1206 - CAPACITOR"  "205.219"   "101.873"   "bottom"
       "C96"    "100-0268"  "1206 - CAPACITOR"  "27.495"    "77.597"    "bottom"
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Is `deleteCodeList` read from a file or is it in memory? I don't follow what the code block is doing.

Comment: You you actually want to delete them, or merely ignore them (presenting the list as if those words were not in it?)

Comment: @JasonFaulkner its one of my another text file which has all the words to delete..

Comment: And is the `[Delete]` section at the end? Otherwise how do you know when it ends? (Actually, could you just give a short sample of each file, that'd make what you're trying to do a lot clearer).

Comment: @JonHanna i want to delete them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second `while()` loop, you don't do anything with `values` or `sb`, returning an empty string to be written. You want to check if any of the tab-separated words are in your `deleteCodeList`, and if not, add it to the stringbuilder:

```
while (!reader.EndOfStream)
{
    var line = reader.ReadLine();
    var values = line.Split('\t').Select(v => v.Trim(' ', '"'));

    bool deleteLine = values.Any(v => deleteCodeList.Any(w => v.Equals(w)));

    if (!deleteLine)
    {
        sb.Append(line + Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
```

Comment: You were too hasty to copy-paste (please try to understand the code before doing that), I ninja-edited `+ Environment.NewLine` in there.

Comment: @yup i know.. sorry about that.. i was thinking how did i missed that... Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @as an extension to this code.. i would like to know what if my input text file has a double quote before and after the each word

Comment: `v.Equals(w)` does the comparison here, where `v` is a tab-delimited word from your line and `w` is a "delete code". You can change that comparison to anything you want, or you can [trim the `v` values of whitespace and quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3281772/c-sharp-regular-expression-remove-leading-and-trailing-double-quotes).

Comment: can u please add as a side note:  to trim the `v` value `if` the input text file contains `double quotes`

Comment: is this correct `var st = old.Trim().Split(new char[] { '\t' });`

Comment: No, that will trim the line before splitting. See edit.

Comment: Using a `HashSet<string>` instead of `List<string>` would be a worthwhile optimisation, since it has a constant-time `Contains()`.

Comment: @JonHanna i got the answer.. now i am wondering how can i do for my words with double quotes and words without double quotes.. please see my updated question